How to tag Entra ID resources, like users, groups, etc., so that the tags can't be changed by resource owners?
As an Entra ID administrator, I want to tag resources, like users, groups, etc., with immutable metadata (e.g. department.)
I have considered the following means of adding custom information to resources through extensions:

Extension attributes
Directory (Microsoft Entra ID) extensions
Schema extensions
Open extensions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=csharp
However, while these extensions allow me to tag any resource, it seems like resource owners can change the attributes, which I don't want. They should be immutable for anyone besides administrators.
How can I accomplish this?
